# API RESTFUL - O que seria

Tags: php, .net, node.js

O que seria uma API RESTFUL?

Qual diferença dela para um Web Service (que possui WebMethods com operaçoes CRUD por exemplo)?

Obrigada

Comment: Não é duplicado, estou questionando a diferença para um Web Service comum também...

Comment: Estava justamente procurando aquela pergunta, la já explica isso também.